# Xamarin Android passing variable from Activity to Fragment returns null

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm trying to pass variables from my main activity to a fragment. This is how i'm attempting to do it:

This is in my Activity:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle (); 
    args.PutString ("header", header);
    args.PutString ("content", content);
    args.PutString ("footer", header);
    args.PutString ("imageLocation", imageLocation);

    exhibitMainFragment.Arguments = args;

    FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ()
        .Replace (Resource.Id.main_view, exhibitMainFragment)
        .AddToBackStack (null)
        .Commit ();
```

This is in my Fragment:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MuseumInformation, null);

            content = this.Activity.Intent.GetStringExtra ("content");
            header = this.Activity.Intent.GetStringExtra ("header");
            footer = this.Activity.Intent.GetStringExtra ("footer");
            imageFilePath = this.Activity.Intent.GetStringExtra ("imageLocation");
```

But none of the variables are being passed (they are all empty in the fragment). I'm clearly making a fundamental error here. Can somebody tell me what it is please. Or show me a better way to pass the data across.

Thanks.

Comment: `this.Activity.Intent.GetStringExtra` => `Arguments.GetString` ?

Answer (score 3):

This is how i did it:

```
content = Arguments.GetString("content"); 
header = Arguments.GetString ("header");
footer = Arguments.GetString("footer");
imageFilePath = Arguments.GetString ("imageLocation");
```

Answer (score 3):

**In the Activity**

```
Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
mybundle.PutString("MyDataTag", "Hello");

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
var myFragment = new VerifyReportFragment();
myFragment .Arguments = mybundle;
```

**in the Fragment OnCreateView**

```
String stringData= Arguments.GetString("MyDataTag");
```